# Is it possible to burn a live image to a damaged pendrive?

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb, badblocks

I have a 16G pendrive that has some bad blocks:

```
# f3read /media/morfik/224e0447-1b26-4c3e-a691-5bf1db650d21
                  SECTORS      ok/corrupted/changed/overwritten
Validating file 1.h2w ... 2097112/       40/      0/      0
Validating file 2.h2w ... 2097120/       32/      0/      0
Validating file 3.h2w ... 2097098/       54/      0/      0
Validating file 4.h2w ... 2097148/        4/      0/      0
Validating file 5.h2w ... 2097114/       38/      0/      0
Validating file 6.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 7.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 8.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 9.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 10.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 11.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 12.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 13.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 14.h2w ... 2097152/        0/      0/      0
Validating file 15.h2w ...   90664/        0/      0/      0

  Data OK: 14.05 GB (29450624 sectors)
Data LOST: 84.00 KB (168 sectors)
             Corrupted: 84.00 KB (168 sectors)
      Slightly changed: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
           Overwritten: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
Average reading speed: 18.77 MB/s
```

As you can see only the first five gigs have damaged sectors. The rest is fine. The problem is when I try to burn a live image to this pendrive, the action stops after transferring 50MiB.

Is there a way to skip the 5G from the beginning and place the image after the damaged space, so it could boot without a problem?

Comment: You don't need all that `grub`/MBR/VBR stuff - if you can partition the disk just format an EFI system partition, put your kernel on there, and boot it.

Comment: Such a feature would probably not be needed very often. So I'd be surprised if anybody spend time automating it.

Comment: The first 5G of this pendrive died because of the images -- they utilize only a few gigs and always from the beginning of the device. So I think that someone should do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem, but I'm still wonder if there's a better and easier solution.

Anyways, if you have bad blocks at the beginning of the device and you are unable to burn a live image, you should make two partitions:

[image]

Then you download an image and check its first partition's offset:

```
# parted  /home/morfik/Desktop/debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-mate-desktop.iso
(parted) unit s

(parted) print
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/morfik/Desktop/debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-mate-desktop.iso: 2015232s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      64s    2015231s  2015168s  primary               boot, hidden
```

So it's 64 sectors, which means 64*512=32768bytes . Now we are able to mount this image:

```
# mount -o loop,offset=32768 /home/morfik/Desktop/debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-mate-desktop.iso /mnt
 mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

# ls -al /mnt
total 593K
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 16:09:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K 2015-06-08 20:54:43 ../
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 16:08:34 .disk/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 15:59:10 dists/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 16:09:41 install/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 16:08:29 isolinux/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 16:08:29 live/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 15:59:00 pool/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root root 2.0K 2015-06-06 16:09:37 tools/
-r--r--r--  1 root root  133 2015-06-06 16:09:44 autorun.inf
lr-xr-xr-x  1 root root    1 2015-06-06 15:59:10 debian -> ./
-r--r--r--  1 root root 177K 2015-06-06 16:09:44 g2ldr
-r--r--r--  1 root root 8.0K 2015-06-06 16:09:44 g2ldr.mbr
-r--r--r--  1 root root  28K 2015-06-06 16:09:57 md5sum.txt
-r--r--r--  1 root root 360K 2015-06-06 16:09:44 setup.exe
-r--r--r--  1 root root  228 2015-06-06 16:09:44 win32-loader.ini
```

We have access to the files so we can copy them to the prendrive's second partition:

```
# cp -a /mnt/* /media/morfik/good
```

The following command will hardcode the second partition into MBR in order to boot from it:

```
printf '\x2' | cat /usr/lib/SYSLINUX/altmbr.bin - | dd bs=440 count=1 iflag=fullblock conv=notrunc of=/dev/sdb
```

I'm using ext4 filesystem on the second partition, so I have to use extlinux, but the image has isolinux. I don't have to remove this folder, I can change its name instead:

```
# mv isolinux extlinux
```

Tha same thing I have to do with the config file inside of that folder:

```
# mv isolinux.cfg extlinux.conf
```

I'm not sure whether this step is necessary, but I always copy all the files anyway:

```
# cp /usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/* /media/morfik/good/extlinux/
```

The last thing is to install extlinux's VBR on the second partition:

```
# extlinux -i /media/morfik/good/extlinux/
/media/morfik/good/extlinux/ is device /dev/sdb2
```

And that's pretty much it. I tested the image, it boots and the live system works well. This solution should work for all kind of live images.

Answer (score 1):

If there is enough space at the beginning of the drive to install GRUB (or any other bootloader really), and the LiveCD supports loop-mounting ISO, you can create a filesystem that has the bad blocks mapped out or you can partition it to avoid bad blocks in the first place.

Example `grub.cfg` boot entry for a Ubuntu Live CD:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop amd64" {
    set isofile="ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,msdos3)/$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/$isofile noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

So GRUB2 is very fancy in that it extracts even the kernel and initramfs directly from the ISO file. But this feature is entirely superfluous if, in addition to the ISO, you loop mount it yourself and copy the kernel and initramfs files standalone, so you have three files in your `/boot`: the kernel, the initramfs, and the iso file.

That way you can use any bootloader of your choice, so in another bootloader it might look like this:

```
linux vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso noprompt noeject
initrd initrd.lz
```

The parameters are different for every flavour of CD since the loop mounting and iso file hunting is handled by the Live CD's initramfs itself.

Normally this technique is used to put a large number of Live CDs onto a single USB stick. It just happens to work in avoiding bad block regions as well (if partitioned / formatted properly).

Comment: I think I have an easier solution, but I have to check it first, and if it works I'll post it here.